# How can I rewrite the .length() property using slice()?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is my assignment:

> By now you should have worked with the length property of strings, e.g. "hello".length. Your task is to write a function called stringLength that accepts a string as a parameter and computes the length of that string; however, as you may have guessed, you are not allowed to use the length property of the string!
>
> Instead, you'll need to make use of the string method called slice.
> For our purposes, we can consider slice as taking one argument -- the index to begin slicing from, and returns a new string starting from that index onwards.

This is what I tried:

```
function stringLength(string){
  var count = count++;
  if(string.slice(0)){
     return count}
 return  stringLength(string.slice(0,-1)) 
 }
console.log(stringLength("game"))
```

I am trying to slice each character of the string back to start index, index 0, and then accumulate my count variable. I do not understand why my count variable is not accumulating.

Comment: That's different definition of `slice` than what javascript uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iterative proposal.

```js
function stringLength(string) {
    var count = 0;
    while (string) {
        string = string.slice(1);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(stringLength("game"));
```

A recursive proposal.

```js
function stringLength(string) {
    return string ? 1 + stringLength(string.slice(1)) : 0;
}

console.log(stringLength("game"));
```

Comment: I think my problem was I did not set count to 0? maybe that's why it was not accumulating?

Comment: not only, you need to `return 1 + stringLength(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm i tried to write code in the same format that you did.

```
function stringLength(str, count){
  if(!str.slice(0)){
     return count;
  }
    return  stringLength(str.slice(0,-1), ++count) 
 }
console.log(stringLength("game", 0))
```

I'll point out the mistakes in your original code so that its easy to understand.

1. The recursion base case was incorrect. `string.slice(0)` will return
   true if the string is non-empty, so use `!string.slice(0)`
2. The count value was not initialized and it wasn't being passed down
   the recursion.

Comment: this is the best website ever

Comment: Thanks. Do mark a correct answer and help close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You really should try to figure it out yourself. Otherwise, are you really learning the subject?

```
function stringLength(string) {
  if(!string) return 0;
  var length = -1;
  while(string.slice(length) !== string) --length;
  return -length;
}
```

A variation taking into account your odd definition of `slice()`:

```
function stringLength(string) {
  var length = 0;
  while(string.slice(length) !== "") ++length;
  return length;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, im not really too sure what to say I've been stuck on this problem since last night and I've posted one of my many other attempts. Does this still not satisfy SO etiquette? I honestly was just wondering why my count variable wasnt accumulating

Comment: @heliu `string.slice(0)` returns your entire string so, unless the string is empty, it's a truthy value. This means your `if` statement almost always runs.

Comment: thanks for the answer though, i have not looked entirely at one yet, trying to do what i can with the hints. awesome thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your count variable is a separate variable for each function invocation, so it will always get the same value and not keep incrementing.

You could use this:

```js
function stringLength(string){
    return string ? 1 + stringLength(string.slice(0,-1)) : 0; 
}
console.log(stringLength("game"))
```

A bit shorter would be to take out the first character instead of the last:

```
    return string ? 1 + stringLength(string.slice(1)) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to use recursion like this:

```
function stringLength(string) {
    if (string) {
        return 1 + stringLength(string.slice(1))
    } else return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stringLength(string) {
    var len = 0;
    while (string) {
        string = string.substring(1);
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

console.log(stringLength("boss"));
```

this works as well.